# Add Column to SAS via Proc SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sas

I haven't been able to find this exact question - but it seems simple enough that it's likely been asked before. I apologize in advance if my search skills aren't up to par...

Anyhow, I am trying to create a 'source_flag' column, appended to several tables I'm creating. Basically, each year and payment type has it's own table. I can query and manipulate each table individually, but I'm joining them all together (full join) at the end of the process. I want to create a column with each observation equal to the table the data came from.

For example, I want to join six tables:

2019_PD

2020_PD

2019_PB

2020_PB

2019_PN

2020_PN

All I want to do, is in the query for each table, create a column assigning the table name to the entire row, so that I know where each row came from.

```
proc sql;

create table 2020_PD as select
 ...,
 ...,
 ...,
 "2020_PD"          as source_flg,
 .
 .
 .
  ;
quit;
```

Right now SAS is trying to find a field called 2020_PD - which obviously doesn't exist. Is there an easy way to do this within the proc statement? I'm not trying to add additional data steps since I'm doing this with too many tables to make that viable.

Thank you!!

Comment: Is it an append then? If it's an APPEND, look into the SET statement option INDSNAME which will append all data sets together and add a field of the source data set. A join could theoretically be sourced from multiple tables, couldn't it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to better learn how to format your question. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: It is an append, yes - and thank you for the formatting tips. 

I was able to get it figured out. I think the quotes were throwing it off, using apostrophes seemed to resolve it. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

SQL uses single quotes to delimit strings.  So use:

```
'2020_PD' as source_flg,
```

The double quotes are interpreted as escape characters for an identifier, which is why you are getting an unknown column error.